# Replace the UIImageView with UILabel in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I want to create a `UITableViewCell` that is very similar to the standard `UITableViewCell` with the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`. The user is able to select a cell and the a checkmark should be set on that selected cell.

I want to display a `UILabel` instead of the `UIImage` in the left part of the cell. I have tried to add a `UILabel` to the `contentView`. The `UILabel` is displayed above both the text and the detailed text label. I would like to move both the text and the detailed text to the right when my the `UILabel` expands to the right, just as with the `UIImage`.

I know to make a custom cell in Interface Builder, but then I do it I don't know how to get the checkmark image, the one that is used when setting the `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`. There is the disclosure available as a button (and several others), but the checkmark does not seems to be available. Is there a way to get the checkmark icon and use it in a custom cell in Interface Builder? I don't want to make my own checkmark.

I have searched the Internet and Stackoverflow, but I cannot find the answer to my question. I guess I am missing a crucial part, but I cannot figure this one out by myself.

Are there any free open source or creative commons replacements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding everything correctly, it seems like the easiest thing to do would be to not use the built in text and detail text on the cell and customize those labels as well.

Then in your:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` adjust the width/offset of your labels as necessary.

For the checkmark, if you're not adjusting where the disclosure image appears you should just be able to set it with `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

Answer (score 1):

If by "checkmark" you mean a box with a tick or similar that the user can switch on or off with a tap, then I'm afraid you're out of luck, as cocoa-touch contains no such control.

However, rolling your own is easier than you might think. You simply need a pair or png images for the graphics (one for 'checked' and one for 'unchecked'). There are thousands of free icons and buttons available on the web.

Then you can create a custom `UIButton` like this:

```
UIButton *checkmark = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkmark setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkmark setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

You can then check the state of the button (whether it is checked or not) using the `selected` property. For more info on `selected` see the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

Comment: I refer to the checkmark set by the property UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Answer (score 1):

Rather create a custom cell programmatically.

There is sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318).

Also for the checkmark you can add

`cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

to your

`tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier` or in

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` 
whichever will suit your app.